# How to display props in the html format in React function component?

Tags: reactjs

Want to pass customized html element into function component, but seems it's treated as plain string.

```
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="t21.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The js file is

```
const InfoMsg = (props) => {
    return <div>
        {props.parm}
        </div>;
}

const Hello = (props) => {
        console.log(props);
        let divElem;

        switch (props.type)
        {
            case 'info':
                divElem = InfoMsg(props);
                break;
        }

    return divElem;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello type='info' parm='<h2>info</h2>' />, document.getElementById('mydiv'));
```

How to let InfoMsg return `<div><h2>info</h2></div>` ? Right now it's returning `<div>"<h2>info</h2>"</div>.`

Comment: If you want to render a string containing HTML as actual HTML (not usually recommended, as it can be risky) then you need this: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing it through as a string.
Therefor it will display as a string.

You can try: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` option.
Or you could pass it through as a dom object.

```
<Hello type='info' parm={<h2>info</h2>} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i get most of the code working. Now the question is on your solution 2, pass as a dom object. Believe my inputs should be strings, how to convert the string '<h2>info</h2>' to dom object pls ?

Comment: i'm trying this but not working yet, let str='<h2>info</h2>'; 
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
<Hello type='info' parm={doc} />  it says Minified React error.

Comment: @user3552178 If it is a string, then you might just have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. I've found that sometimes you just have to do it. It's more of a last case scenario